# sql query not working in my webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

I wrote a MySQL query in my PHP code to join two tables, but I don't want all the columns in the result

My place details table:

[image: my place details table pic]

My registration table:

[image: my registration table oic]

**My Code**

```
         <?php
$con=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

        if(!$con)
       {
           die('not connected');
       }
            $result=  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT placedetails.name,placedetails.doj,placedetails.total,placedetails.stay,placedetails.food,placedetails.travel,registration.username 
          FROM placedetails inner join registration on placedetails.id=registration.id ;" );



?>
<div class="container">
<CENTER><h2>view Booking Details</h2> 
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <th>place</th>
  <th>Travelling Date</th>
  <th>Total Cost</th>
  <th>Stay cost</th>
  <th>Food cost</th>
  <th>Travelling cost</th>
  <th>User ID</th>


        <?php

             while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))

             {
                 ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['doj']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['total'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stay'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['food'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['travel'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'] ;?></td>

                <td><img src='".$row['choose']."'/></td>";
            </tr>
        <?php
             }
             ?>
             </table>
            </div>
```

i wrote my code,its executing but the problem is the data is not executing,can someone please help me out with my problem.

Comment: Try running this query in your phpmyadmin and see if you get any results

Comment: same like web its showng onlt the colum names and my and my values inside id's colum of both tables are not same @Akin

Comment: if the id's dont match then u wont get any results

Comment: then how to change my id number in phpmyadmin @vSugumar

Comment: it's also important to know if query returns something, num_rows > 0 and use an else condition. NOTE: use prepared statements and allow error_reporting on top of the page

Comment: In your MysqlAdmin you have a chanche button, I would not do that, your ID key has to be unique. I would create a pseudo ID_regist key in your table placedetails. And then assign the ID's corresponding to your table Regist

Answer (score 0):

MysqlAdmin

In your table place details create a new entry call ID_regist.
After that change or give a number that correspond to your id in tabel Regist.

code php

For the connection create a connection.php.

```
<?php
     $con=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

        if(!$con)
       {
           die('not connected');
       }
?>
```

Makes your database more difficult to attack

Main code

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
?>
<div class="container">

<CENTER><h2>view Booking Details</h2> 
<table class="table table-bordered">

<th>place</th>
<th>Travelling Date</th>
<th>Total Cost</th>
<th>Stay cost</th>
<th>Food cost</th>
<th>Travelling cost</th>
<th>User ID</th>

<?php 
    $sql= 
    "SELECT ". 
    "pld.name, ".
    "pld.doj, ". 
    "pld.total, ".
    "pld.stay, ".
    "pld.food, ".
    "pld.travel, ".
    "pld.username ".
    "FROM placedetails pld ".
    "inner join registration reg ".
    "on pld.ID_regist=reg.id;";
    $result=  mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($result){
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['doj']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['total'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stay'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['food'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['travel'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'] ;?></td>
                <td><img src='".$row['choose']."'/></td>"; // first there is no row, call chose
            </tr>
<?php
       }
     }
     else{
       die("Error"); //Something of the type mysqli_error(connection);
     }
?>
       </table>
 </div>
```

Attention to the row call chose, that you don't use in your sql query.
If that does not solve your problems, tell me what happens when I try to help you.

Comment: tq u for the code,i am doing a tours and travls website where users book packages that are availabe in the website,the main problem is i have 2 pages one is admin page nd another is user page. if a user login into the website and he select any tour package and book  then in admin page there is a table where i want the user name the the package he selected , if possible can you provid that sql query @Jose Marques

Comment: So if I undersand, you have a client regist tabel and a tabel call placedetails. You want to store the data when the client choose, so that the administrator knows that this client chose those specific data? If this is what you want, you have to think a bit more about your database, and how you can use it to create a relationship between tables that allows you to do what you want. If you do not know what a table relation is, search on google.If you have any difficulty ask me that I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the place table and add registration_id. Then join with this field.

```
SELECT placedetails.name,placedetails.doj,placedetails.total,placedetails.stay,placedetails.food,placedetails.travel,registration.username 
FROM placedetails inner join registration on registration.id=place.registration_id
```